# Can you help me convert this React star rating?

Tags: reactjs

Can you help me convert this code to convert the rating number to a 5-star rating by dividing the rating by 2 and
if the index of the star is < Math.floor(rating / 2) - 1 then color it with maroon else make it grey? As much explanation as possible would be helpful.

```
export default function StarRating({ totalStars = 5 }) {
    const [selectedStars, setSelectedStars] = useState(0);
    return (
       <>
       {createArray(totalStars).map((n, i) => (
       <Star
          key={i}
          selected={selectedStars > i}
          onSelect={() => setSelectedStars(i + 1)}
       />
    ))}
      <p>
       {selectedStars} of {totalStars} stars
      </p>
      </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What's not working with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see what create array does, does it do something like this? If not this could be the solution for you

```
  export default function StarRating({ totalStars = 5 }) {
    const [selectedStars, setSelectedStars] = useState(0);
    var totalStarsArray = [];
    for(var j = 1;j <= totalStars;j++)
    {
        totalStarsArray.push(j);
    }
    return (
       <>
       {totalStarsArray.map((n, i) => (
       <Star
          key={n}
          selected={selectedStars > n}
          onSelect={() => setSelectedStars(n+ 1)}
       />
    ))}
      <p>
       {selectedStars} of {totalStars} stars
      </p>
      </>
  );
}
```